# jQuery onclick to vanish the div itis located in

Tags: jquery, select

I have the following situation:

```
<div class='err'> 
Error 1
<span>
<a title='ignore'>x</a>
</span>
</div>

<div class='err'> 
Error 2
<span>
<a title='ignore'>x</a>
</span>
</div>
```

The 'errors' are displayed in this form. What I want is: when the x is clicked the div in which the x is located to vanish. !?

```
$('.err span a ??').click(function() {
    $(this .err ??).hide();
});
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use `closest` method.

```
$('.err span a').click(function(e) {
    // e.preventDefault();
    $(this).closest('div.err').hide();
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/eYXff/

Answer (score 1):

Try this

```
$('.err span a').click(function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    $(this).closest('div').hide();
});
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```js
$(function() {

  $('.err span a').on('click', function() {
    $(this).closest(".err").hide();
  });

});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.8.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class='err'>
  Error 1
  <span>
<a title='ignore'>x</a>
</span>
</div>

<div class='err'>
  Error 2
  <span>
<a title='ignore'>x</a>
</span>
</div>
```

If the performance tool I am using is right using the closest method vs the parents method would be faster. Try it here: http://jsperf.com/parents-vs-closest-12829824

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
$(this).parent().next("div").hide();
```